# How to enable heatmap in a specific row of dataframe using seaborn

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to build a case of seaorn heatmap using python where:

1. all the numbers in diagonal and below that should not have heatmap
2. all the numbers above diagonal should have heatmap
3. Out of Different type of Total(total,cum total,%change etc) lines, only 1(2nd from the bottom or 2nd last row) should have the heatmap.

I was able to achive first 2 by creating 2 heatmaps on a single DF by identifying the diagonal elements.

For 3rd point, I have created another DF which has all the elements of 1st DF replaced with NaN and have different Totals.

Now I need to have heatmap enabled for a specific Tootal row, how can i achieve that. Thanks

current piece of code:

```
diagonal_mask = np.eye(len(clv), dtype=bool)

print("diagonal_mask:",diagonal_mask)

cmap_for_diag = sns.color_palette(['white'], as_cmap=True)  # create a one-colored colormap for the diagonal

common_keywords = dict(annot=True, fmt='.2f', linecolor='Black', linewidth=.5, ax=ax)
# create a heatmap for the diagonal
map1 = sns.heatmap(clv, cmap=cmap_for_diag, mask=~diagonal_mask, cbar=False, **common_keywords)
map1.xaxis.tick_top()
# create a heatmap for the rest of the data
map2 = sns.heatmap(clv, cmap = 'Blues', mask=diagonal_mask,cbar=False, **common_keywords)

map3=sns.heatmap(ax = ax, data = df_values, annot = True, fmt='g', cmap=ListedColormap(['Red']),cbar=False,linecolor='Grey',linewidth=.5)
```

map3 is the one which I want to have heatmap for 2nd last row.I need color from dark green to lighter green for positive values and orange to red for negative values.

Comment: To achieve #1 and #2, are you using a boolean mask? Perhaps sharing some [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question, I think you're looking for a mask for your map3.

```
# Create a mask for the third heatmap, same shape as df_values, initializing all with True
map3_mask = np.ones_like(df_values, dtype=bool)

# Modify the mask to enable the heatmap for the second last row, by setting  it to False
heatmap_row_index = len(df_values) - 2
map3_mask[heatmap_row_index, :] = False

# Use the new mask in sns.heatmap() call for map3
map3 = sns.heatmap(ax=ax, data=df_values, annot=True, fmt='g', cmap=ListedColormap(['Red']), mask=map3_mask, cbar=False, linecolor='Grey', linewidth=.5)
```

For your color coding requirements, you can look into `seaborn.diverging_palette()` method, here's a [tutorial](https://m.tutorialspoint.com/seaborn/seaborn_diverging_palette_method.htm) and its [official documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.diverging_palette.html).